# Thomas Kuhn applied to formal sciences

Tags: philosophy-of-science, kuhn

In The Structure of Scientific Revolutions, Thomas Kuhn focuses on the natural sciences.

Are there applications to formal sciences in his works or by others?

In my research in the usual places, I am yet to find papers that clearly focus on this aspect, but maybe I'm just looking for the wrong keyword.
I haven't fully comprehended Kuhn's work yet, I am sorry if I missed crucial parts.

Comment: If I do a quick web search I get loads of relevant hits like https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82657657.pdf and https://www.cse.sc.edu/~mgv/csce190f14/three_paradigms_of_computer_science.pdf among many others. Am I misunerstanding the question?

Comment: No, I think you're correct. Maybe I just sifted through the wrong citing papers... thanks and sorry :|

Comment: See D. Gillies, [Revolutions in Mathematics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutions_in_Mathematics).